# Decompress GZIP string response from a PHP server in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip

I have an existing PHP code that is doing a curl request to a 3rd-party PHP server.

The 3rd-party server returns a GZIP string.

In PHP, I can use `gzdecode` to decode the gzip string.

How can I do it in NodeJS/Javascript? I tried using [decompress-response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress-response) with no avail.

Also tried using [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) instead of `request`, enabled auto-decompress, also doesn't work.

Edit: Also tried `zlib` and `pako`, also doesn't work.

Sample Code [ PHP ]

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $params,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000000,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING  => '',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
   echo false;
} else {
   $response = gzdecode($response);
   echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution that works for me.**

**I used [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) instead of [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) because I can't get it to work there.**

I set my request options:

```
const requestOptions = {
    encoding: null, // this is important
    headers: {
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
    }
    ...
};
```

Don't forget that `encoding: null` line, because without that, the response will be automatically converted to a string. ( We need a buffer to make this work )

Then I created a function like this to handle my request:

```
const zlib = require("zlib");

async function performRequest(url, options) {
    try {
        const response = await got(url, options);
        if (response.headers["content-encoding"] === "gzip") {
            const body = response.body;
            try {
                const dezziped = zlib.gunzipSync(response.body);
                response.body = JSON.parse(dezziped.toString());
            } catch (error) {
                response.body = body;
            }
        }
        return response.body;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is a synchronous operation, you can use `gunzip` instead if you want to do the async way.